# Importing .eps file into Java program

Tags: java, vector, eps, contour

I need to parse an Encapsulated Post Script file into Java program. More specifically, I need to be able to extract simple vectors and curve elements from it, and manipulate them after this. Is there a Java library which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ToastScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/toastscript/) looks like it may be what you are looking for.